# PEP8 formatting: long line with indentation and nested brackets

Tags: python, indentation, brackets, pep8

As a python beginner, I've been looking for a PEP8-compliant way of formatting the following line of code (that also makes PyCharm happy). Here it is:

```
print("{}! The {} {} ".format(self.monster.battlecry(),
                              self.monster.color,
                              self.monster.__class__.__name__)
      + self.monster_deaths.pop(self.monster_deaths.index(random.choice(self.monster_deaths))))
```

I'm especially worried about the last line with the 4 brackets at the end. Also, should I indent the last line by 4 spaces as usual, or a bit more to align it to the content of `print` ?

Would the following be more appropriate?

```
print("{}! The {} {} ".format(self.monster.battlecry(),
                              self.monster.color,
                              self.monster.__class__.__name__)
       + self.monster_deaths.pop(
             self.monster_deaths.index(
                 random.choice(self.monster_deaths)
                 )
             )
      )
```

An alternative would be to shorten this ugly line by creating a variable `d = self.monster_deaths`. What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the alternative to shorten the line with a temporary variable is the right way.  In that case, you can also add it to the format statement rather than using string concatenation:

```
d = self.monster_deaths.pop(...)
print("{}! The {} {} {}".format(self.monster.battlecry(),
                                self.monster.color,
                                type(self.monster).name,
                                d))
```

Comment: +1 for temporary variable, makes it also easier to read through and notice that we are popping something out from the list.